# When will Internet Explorer be deprecated?

Tags: internet-explorer

IE 10 is deprecated. I want to start phasing out support for IE 11 and was wondering if anyone knows when will IE 11 get deprecated?

Comment: It already is; Microsoft discourages its use (preferring Edge) and is no longer guaranteeing patches for it.

Comment: IE has _not_ been end-of-life'd yet though. It is still in the latest build of Win10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely October 14, 2025. This website has a countdown as well as some extra information https://www.whenwillie11die.com/

Answer (score 1):

> Internet Explorer 11 will continue receiving security updates and technical support for the lifecycle of the version of Windows on which it is installed.

Microsoft has a [FAQ page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17454/lifecycle-faq-internet-explorer) stating this, and you can independently [search for specific lifecycles](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/search?alpha=Internet%20Explorer%2011) on their support site.

When it boils down to it, IE11's support is tied to Windows 10 - which will see its [mainstream support ending Oct. 13, 2020, and its extended support ending Oct. 14, 2025](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10#Updates_and_support). It's likely that both of those dates will get pushed further to the right as Microsoft has a history of extending support for operating systems.

Comment: I can't find anywhere in the Wikipedia article that would say Windows 10 support ends in 2020. That's for the "2015 LTSB" branch only – is IE lifetime tied to that even if you're using a more recent Win10 branch?

Comment: The way I was reading the chart, it appears the Long Term Servicing Channel (LTSC) is only given/established for versions 1507, 1607, and 1809 - with those ending in 2025, 2026, and 2029, respectively. The last specified version (1903, the May 2019 update) is currently listed as having support until December 2020.